# Cannot log in to WiFi hotspot on Ubuntu 17.10: Name or service not known

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10, hot-spot

I'm trying to connect to my library's WiFi which previously worked on Ubuntu 17.04 and which is currently working on my phone. However as soon as I log in to Ubuntu (before opening my browser) I get a Hotspot Login popup which reports:

```
Error resolving "aruba.cambridgema.gov": Name or service not known.
```

If I try to visit a page in Chromium I get one tab which says:

> **Connect to Wi-Fi**
>
> The Wi-Fi you are using (Cambridge Public Internet) may require you to visit its login page.

And another tab which says:

> **This site can't be reached**
>
> **aruba.cambridgema.gov**'s server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Firefox also does not work.

I have tried adding:

`supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;`

to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`file and restart `network-manager` to use Google's DNS servers,

I have also tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and reboot, neither of which have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, for me the following fixed the issue:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

Comment: Thanks, Jacob. The problem went away on its own for me, but maybe your answer can help someone else.